# How to highlight row if it is within the dates?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using googlescript and would like to know the code on how I can highlight all rows if the date on a cell is within the specific duration.

example: if cell A2 is within Today()+5 and Today()-3
if yes, then it highlight all row in Gray
if not, then it moves to the next row

Existing code:

```
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('O:O').activate();
    var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('O:O')])
    .whenDateAfter(new Date()).setBackground('#808080'));
    .whenDateAfter(new Date(new Date().getTime()-10*(1000*60*60*24)))
    .whenDateBefore(new Date(new Date().getTime()-10*(1000*60*60*24)))
    .setBackground('#808080')
    .build());
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### High light line if in range

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const dt = new Date()
  const hi = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() + 5).valueOf();
  const lo = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 2).valueOf();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let v = new Date(r[14]).valueOf()
    if(v < lo && v < hi) {
      //sh.getRange(i + 1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground("#ffff00");//highlites line to yellow
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. I tried to use it but nothing happens. Could you pls advise where/how I can insert so that it reads the date on column 'O' then if it meets that date on column O, it will highlight the whole row?

Comment: Could you pls advise how I can use/apply this condition to googlesheet code? IF(AND(DATEVALUE(O:O)>=TODAY()-10,DATEVALUE(O:O)<=TODAY()+1),"YES","NO")

Comment: I also used code below but it not also working:

Comment: var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('O:O').activate();
    var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('O:O')])
    .whenDateAfter(new Date()).setBackground('#808080'));
    .whenDateAfter(new Date(new Date().getTime()-10*(1000*60*60*24)))
    .whenDateBefore(new Date(new Date().getTime()-10*(1000*60*60*24)))
    .setBackground('#808080')
    .build());

Comment: When I provided the answer you had not specified which column the date would be on I modified it to read column O

Comment: Hey cooper, could you pls advise how to delete rows for the same condition?